# Sum of two grouped values in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

```
Trans_Id      Account_Id     Amount   Tran_Type
   1             HA1001       1000       C
   2             HA1001         50       D
   3             HA1001        100       C
   4             HA1001        400       D
```

Now how can I calculate balance amount in my account like `sum of (C) - sum of (D) = 650` ?

Answer (score 1):

The tenary **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator will come in handy for this aggregation operation type. You can use it to calculate the sum given the `Tran_Type` value, so you could inject this logic within the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stage where you will group all the documents (i.e. group by the null key). You would also need to pipe a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator to calculate the difference with the **[`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#exp._S_subtract)** arithmetic operator.

The following example will demonstrate this concept. Run the pipeline operation to get the desired result:

**Populate Test Documents:**

```
db.test.insert([
    {
        "Trans_Id": 1,
        "Account_Id": "HA1001",
        "Amount": 1000,
        "Tran_Type": "C"
    },
    {
        "Trans_Id": 2,
        "Account_Id": "HA1001",
        "Amount": 50,
        "Tran_Type": "D"
    },
    {
        "Trans_Id": 3,
        "Account_Id": "HA1001",
        "Amount": 100,
        "Tran_Type": "C"
    },
    {
        "Trans_Id": 4,
        "Account_Id": "HA1001",
        "Amount": 400,
        "Tran_Type": "D"
    }
])
```

**Aggregation Pipeline:**

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "total_C": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ "$Tran_Type", "C" ] }, 
                        "$Amount", 0 
                    ]
                }
            },
            "total_D": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ "$Tran_Type", "D" ] }, 
                        "$Amount", 0 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "balance": {
                "$subtract": ["$total_C", "$total_D"]
            }, "_id": 0
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output:**

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        { "balance" : 650 }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Need one more help If I have one more column that is Category e.g "Cat1","Cat2".Now how will  I get the balance amount category wise?

Comment: @HassanAhamed Looks like original problem is solved isn't it? As for the "next" problem, that would be a **[different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, consider posting it separately.